# I had handed in projects which were past the deadline

Tags: grammar, past-tense, possessives

Let's say you were storytelling your past academic shortcomings. And you say:

> "I was not a perfect student when I was still studying at school. For instance, I **had handed in projects which were past the deadline**, this is just one those shortcomings I had when I was still a school learner."

Is this sentence construction, particularly the bold letters, **grammatical?**.

- I have used ''**had''** for several projects that were overdue the given date(in the past)--is it correct?
- Also, is it **''the deadline''** or **''the deadlines''** or ''deadlines''?

Comment: Instead of the wordy “which were past the deadline,” you could simply shorten that to “late”: _I handed in projects late_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **had** handed in...

This is past perfect, which is used to talk about something that occurred **before** some other event in the past, for example.

> I had known him for some time when I first met his wife

The other event is meeting his wife, and so I use past perfect to indicate that the knowing occurred before I met his wife.

In your sentence, there is no other event, so you should not use past perfect. Simple past is fine:

> I was not a perfect student when I was still studying at school...

**the deadline** in this case is understood to mean **the deadline [for the project]**. You should not make it plural, because there is only one deadline for each project.

---

A few minor corrections:

> at school. For instance, I ...

It is not normal to start a sentence with **for instance**. It would be better to put a comma before it, rather than a full stop, and omit the comma after it.

> studying at school

What else are you at school for? omit studying.

> deadline, this

**this** is the start of a new sentence. You need a full stop, not a comma

> those shortcomings

**those** would refer to some shortcomings that you have already mentioned... but you have only mentioned one!

> shortcomings I had

this is not idiomatic in this context. better to say "my shortcomings"

> school learner

This is not idiomatic. Say either "student", or "at school". This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=school%20learner%2C%20student&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cschool%20learner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstudent%3B%2Cc0) shows just how uncommon it is.

Putting that all together, you get:

> I was not a perfect student when I was at school, for instance I handed in projects which were past the deadline. This was just one of my shortcomings as a student.

The last sentence is actually redundant, because "for instance" makes it clear that this is just one of many failings.

Comment: Regarding your very last sentence, I think it should be ''This was just one of my shortcomings when I was still a school learner.''(your not a student now) also, I changed the 'student' word at the end coz I don't wat to repeat the word itself. What's your take on this?

Comment: As I pointed out, **school learner** is not idiomatic: see the NGram that I provided a link to. "You're not a student now..." the expression "as a student" in this context means "when I was a student". If you don't want to repeat student, replace "as a student" with "at school" or "back then".